# Add databound dropdown to Azure API App logic app shape

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have developed an azure API app that I am using in a logic app. For the purpose of this post, it doesn't matter what my app does.

In my logic app shape (Azure API App) I have managed to render a drop down list by making one of my API post params an ENUM. Then changing the swagger / swashbuckle configuration to render the definition differently.

This is a good start but I really need a data driven drop down that reads it's data from a constantly changing data source (blobs, documentDB for example but it doesn't matter).

I can't find any posts on this.

All help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question - we have on our backlog to support what we call "Dynamic Swagger" that lets you do just this.  I'm hoping it will be in production near the beginning of March.  In the meantime you will need to just enter in the values of those fields manually.

Comment: thanks for this. I'll stop look now. Just wondering **where** this we be announced? Azure Advisors? @jeffhollan